What string comes next?
What string comes next:

accccfjuyz
fhqsstv
cfgiorttv
cfffgiioorsttuvz
abccffgioorttvz
aabcccdffghimooqrssttvzzz

Hint:

 Separation

Hint 2:

 A sequence from 0 to 6 (6 is missing)

Hint 3:

 Where does donut = coffee cup?


The next string is

 abccdfffghimooqrsstttvzz

because

 If you ROT12 an item, the decrypted form is an anagram of the name of the $T_x$ space in topology, where x is the index of the item in the list.
 0. accccfjuyz => moooorvgkl => Kolmogorov
 1. fhqsstv => rtceefh => Fréchet
 2. cfgiorttv => orsuadffh => Hausdorff
 3. cfffgiioorsttuvz => orrrsuuaadeffghl => Regular Hausdorff
 4. abccffgioorttvz => mnoorrsuaadffhl => Normal Hausdorff
 5. aabcccdffghimooqrssttvzzz => mmnoooprrstuyaacdeeffhlll => Completely normal Hausdorff
 6. Perfectly normal Hausdorff => dsftsqhzmbcfaozvoigrcftt => abccdfffghimooqrsstttvzz

Notes/Feedback:

 Cool puzzle! In hindsight this was very solvable, even if you don't know the names. But I would've liked the hints to refer to the path you are supposed to take (i.e. ROT cipher, then rearrange) first rather than hinting at what the solution is about. I solved it after the very strong hint 3:


Perfectly normal answer! I agree with your comments, though. (Hadn't seen the last hint.)

I will consider doing that next time.
